# SQL DB on AWS with Power BI Embedded

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I need your help.
We have a plan to run "SQL DB and Web services" on AWS and need to publish the Power BI report by embedding to web service running on AWS. 
Do you think it's possible scenario?  IF yes, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't embed Power BI in a web **service**, so I will assume you want to embed it in a web **application**.

You need at least three components in such architecture - a place to store your data (assuming it will be in some kind of SQL Server), Power BI (assuming Power BI Service) and web application.

The database can be managed by your cloud provider (e.g. [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/)) or "normal" instance running in a VM in the cloud. Of course, it could be something else (not SQL Server), or even be in a different cloud (e.g. Azure), or on-premise. The point is that you store your data there and use this as a data source for your reports.

The you need Power BI to create reports. Assuming that you will use Power BI Service (the online portal), you will design your reports in Power BI Desktop, getting data from your data source, and publishing these reports to Power BI Service. At this point you can view these reports in the portal using the browser. Power BI Service will render them using shared resources. For embedding and relatively heavy usage, you should buy a capacity. Think for capacities as resources (CPU, memory) dedicated only for you. They are not shared with other Power BI users. There are different licensing models and ways to buy a capacity. You can buy [Power BI Premium](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-premium/) or [Azure SKUs](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-embedded-capacity-based-skus-coming-to-azure/). This [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-faq#what-is-the-difference-between-the-a-skus-in-azure-and-the-em-skus-in-office-365) tries to explain the differences, but in general A SKU means "pay what you use, stop at any moment, without any commitments", while EM SKU and P SKU are for bigger scale projects with monthly or yearly commitment. When you buy a capacity, you can assign it to a workspace containing your reports, and then they will be rendered using your own dedicated resources (which should give you better performance).

And the last part is your application (assuming web application, which you can host in [Amazon Web Hosting](https://aws.amazon.com/websites/) or in VM), where you want to embed your reports. Generally speaking, there are two scenarios - "user own data" and "app own data". In the first, each of your users needs Azure AD account. Using this account, he will get access to the reports and data, as he has in the Power BI Service itself. In the second scenario, your app uses one "master" account to access the Power BI, thus your users doesn't need their own accounts in Azure AD. You can use your own authentication in your app. Embedding Power BI is quite large topic and your question isn't specific, so I will recommend to start with [Embedding with Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedding) article, take a look at [Power BI Embedded Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html) and review the [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples).